# php round/ceil/floor how to make a number to Multiples of 7

Tags: php

Firstly poor of my mathematica. I tried to use php to make a number to Multiples of 7. the rules as below:

```
$num >=0;

$num = '0'; => output '7'    
$num = '1'; => output '7'
$num = '6'; => output '7'
$num = '8'; => output '14'
$num = '14'; => output '14'
$num = '16'; => output '21'
$num = '20'; => output '21'
$num = '40'; => output '42'
$num = '84'; => output '84'
...
```

I cost many times, but I am not smart to solve this by myself. such as

```
 echo round(($num*7-1)/7); // not a right answer.
```

any one is kindly help me? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks all, so there have many ways do this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your requirements are not consistent if the output for 0 is 7; 0 is already a multiple of 7, since 0 * 7 = 0.

```
echo ceil($num / 7) * 7;
```

Alternatively, use the modulus operator:

```
$m = $num % 7;
echo $m == 0 ? $num : $num - $m + 7;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `ceil($num / 7) * 7`.  The code:

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
  echo get_number($i) . "\n";
}

function get_number($num) {
  return ceil($num / 7) * 7;
}

?>
```

Produces:

```
0 => 0
1 => 7
2 => 7
3 => 7
4 => 7
5 => 7
6 => 7
7 => 7
8 => 14
9 => 14
10 => 14
11 => 14
12 => 14
13 => 14
14 => 14
15 => 21
...
46 => 49
47 => 49
48 => 49
49 => 49
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use modulo arithmetic, e.g.:

```
$x = $whatever;
while($x % 7 != 0){
   $x++
}

echo $x; // will now be next multipe of seven >= $whatever
```

Comment: This fails spectacularly if someone enters `0.1`.

Comment: The OP example suggested integers, but I agree that your solution is cleaner and also loop-free.